# NiFi LDAP login issue The supplied username and password are not valid

Tags: authentication, ldap, apache-nifi

i'm trying login to nifi with LDAP. but NiFi UI say username/password is not valid. but ldapsearch command is working good, so i think my login-identity-providers.xml file have something wrong syntax.

using nifi-1.8.0, 3-node secured cluster(node01 is ldap server), centos7.

all node have hosts info each other(/etc/hosts)

below code is my login-identity-providers.xml

```
<provider>
    <identifier>ldap-provider</identifier>
    <class>org.apache.nifi.ldap.LdapProvider</class>
    <property name="Authentication Strategy">SIMPLE</property>

    <property name="Manager DN">CN=ldap_admin,DC=mapr,DC=com</property>
    <property name="Manager Password">****</property>

    <property name="TLS - Keystore"></property>
    <property name="TLS - Keystore Password"></property>
    <property name="TLS - Keystore Type"></property>
    <property name="TLS - Truststore"></property>
    <property name="TLS - Truststore Password"></property>
    <property name="TLS - Truststore Type"></property>
    <property name="TLS - Client Auth"></property>
    <property name="TLS - Protocol"></property>
    <property name="TLS - Shutdown Gracefully"></property>

    <property name="Referral Strategy">FOLLOW</property>
    <property name="Connect Timeout">10 secs</property>
    <property name="Read Timeout">10 secs</property>

    <property name="Url">ldap://node01:389/</property>
    <property name="User Search Base">OU=NIFI,DC=mapr,DC=com</property>
    <property name="User Search Filter">(uid={0})</property>

    <property name="Identity Strategy">USE_USERNAME</property>
    <property name="Authentication Expiration">12 hours</property>
</provider>
```

i tried     *ldapsearch -h node01 -p 389 -D 'CN=ldap_admin, DC=mapr, DC=com' -w **** -b 'OU=NIFI, DC=mapr, DC=com' -s sub uid='test03'*  command

it give me a test03 user info,

## test03, NIFI, mapr.com

dn: cn=test03,ou=NIFI,dc=mapr,dc=com

//skip//

uid: test03

mail: test03@nifi.com

userPassword:: /*passwd*/

## search result

search: 2

result: 0 Success

## numResponses: 2

## numEntries: 1

so i tried to login with " user : test03, password ----------- ", but didn't working "The supplied username and password are not valid."

file is wrong? or maybe my ldap server setting is wrong?

Comment: In your XML config, can you try making the white space in the user search base match the white space in your ldap search example? In some contexts, DNs are white space sensitive. If that does not fix the issue, I would enable debug logging in NIFI and check the server logs for your failed login.

Comment: I have similar issue, did you get your problem solved?

Comment: Same problem here ! Any solutions ?